# How to get text from bs4.BeautifulSoup string if two span have same class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
data = "Purchase requests: <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promot">6008067</span><br>Start               price: <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">15,84 pуб.</span>"

sosoup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
ququotes = sosoup.find_all('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote")
print(ququotes)
```

This code return me

```
[<span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">6007813</span>, <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">15,82 pуб.</span>]
```

if i try

```
ququotes = sosoup.find('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote").get_text()
```

it's return me only first one number, how to get a second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches, select by index:

```
sosoup.find_all('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote")[1].text
```

Find first and than its next `<span>`:

```
sosoup.find('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote").find_next('span').text
```

Or with `css selectors` and next sibling (~):

```
sosoup.select_one('span.market_commodity_orders_header_promote ~ span').text
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ququotes = [i.get_text() for i in sosoup.find_all('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote")]
```

or

```
f = sosoup.find_all('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote")[0].get_text()
s = sosoup.find_all('span', class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote")[1].get_text()
```